# Issue in accessing the Neo4j Graph DB in Console

Tags: neo4j

My Graph DB path is

```
db= new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("D:\\Neo_Database\\DB1" );
```

Configured the same path in neo4j-server.properties file

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=D:/Neo_Database/DB1
```

im trying to accessing the Graph using    http//   :7474/db/data/    url.

but im getting below error.

```
HTTP ERROR 503

Problem accessing /db/data/. Reason:

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
Caused by:

javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:458)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.startJetty(Jetty6WebServer.java:330)
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.start(Jetty6WebServer.java:154)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:348)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:183)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
```

Pl help how to access the graph in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "http// :7474/db/data/" is not a valid url. The default url is `http://localhost:7474/db/data/`
2. How are you trying to access the server when you get the error?
3. You cannot access the database as a server and as an embedded instance at the same time unless you deploy a server extension for this purpose, see [Access Neo4j in server mode with EmbeddedGraphDatabase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921388/access-neo4j-in-server-mode-with-embeddedgraphdatabase)